# Я создал расширения для хрома)И мне нужно увеличить в размерах окно которое открылось при нажатии на иконку расширения)

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome

Я создал расширения для хрома)И мне нужно увеличить в размерах окно которое открылось при нажатии  на иконку расширения)

[image: Как увеличить окно розширения?]

Comment: Описывайте свою проблему более подробно. При необходимости, добавьте код, в котором может быть ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать сделать с помощью css стилей. 
К примеру :

```
body{
  width:900px;
  height:900px;
}
```

И получите окно размером 900×900.